# file_get_contents grab remote page, content is not updated

Tags: php

In my localhost PHP file test.php, I use php function file_get_contents to grab a forum index page.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.XX.com/forum.php');
```

when the forum data, sunch as  posting , member changes, I refresh the test.php, content is hasn't changed, I want to know why?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to be able to help. Is your script running at all? Is it getting any information when it runs? Is it getting the right information? Are you writing anything to your local copy?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible reasons:

- You are behind a caching proxy server and are receiving a cached copy of the page

  - This can exist at the network or server level
- The target site detects such requests and provides cached versions for performance or security reasons
- Your browser has cached the output of your script.

You will need to examine your configuration, talk to your network administrator, or check your own browser's cache to find the source of the problem.

Comment: I find reason is the no.2, The test site is a hacker website, could you give a brief about the security reasons.

Comment: Website publishers generally gear their content toward visitors on their own site. When someone 'scrapes' their site content in the manner that you are doing, the publisher is potentially losing valuable users and advertising dollars. Additionally, there is the possibility that the scraper will use the data for their own benefit. For these reasons, publishers may try to limit third-party access to their site through automated means.