# file_get_contents doesn't update the data

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to fetch gamerscore data from gamercard.xbox.com with my little script:

**test.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$regex = '/<div id=\"Gamerscore\">(.+?)<\/div>/';
$gamertag = 'Stallion83';

try {
    $URL = file_get_contents('http://gamercard.xbox.com/en-US/' . $gamertag . '.card');

    if ($URL == false) {
        echo 'Error!';
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}

preg_match($regex, $URL, $gs);

// Extract integer value from string
$gamerscore = filter_var($gs[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// Force gs_int to be integer so it can be used with number_format later
$gs_int = (int)$gamerscore;

$textFile = 'data/gamerscore_' . $gamertag . '.txt';

// Save gamerscore value into everyone's own txt file
file_put_contents($textFile, $gs_int);
?>
```

Now this works and it creates a .txt file in the data folder which has only the gamerscore number inside. But my problem is if I run the script again after the gamerscore value has increased the script doesn't give me any errors and it seems to execute just fine but the gamerscore value it saves into the .txt file is the old value.

I can go to the URL http://gamercard.xbox.com/en-US/Stallion83.card and see the number is different than my script shows.

I thought it might be a caching issue but I think file_get_contents doesn't use caching.

Is there anything else I could set for file_get_contents to force it to get the most recent content of the URL specified? I tried using timeout but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Just a different problem to consider: maybe the file is not being saved with the new value (for whatever reason).

Comment: Echoing $gamerscore or $gs_int still gives the old value

Comment: Maybe it's a server-side caching.

Comment: [file_get_contents grab remote page, content is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464657/file-get-contents-grab-remote-page-content-is-not-updated)

Comment: Most likely it's a server-side caching because I tried cURL as well and it also gives the old number to me. Is there any (legal) way to get around that caching?

Comment: This generally works for client-side caching, but try adding something to the end of the url, eg `?foo`. Other than that, I don't know..

Comment: Holy crap! I changed the url to  $gamertag . 'card?' . mt_rand() and now it gives me the updated score! Awesome, thank you! Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept it as the correct one.

Comment: Have you seen [this api](https://xboxapi.com)? I used it in the past for returning xbox data, worked well for me.

Comment: Yeah I have an account there but I wanted to see if I could build my own little script from scratch :) I'm not too experienced with PHP yet but making progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likelly caused by **cache**. In this case, the **server** seems to be **returning a cached version of the page**.

Often, adding a random value to the URL can be a workaround, such as `?foo`.

So, in your case, something like:

```
[...] . $gamertag . 'card?' . mt_rand());
```